# Better way to manage Database class for common operations

Tags: mysql, windows-services

Our company work on multiple **Windows Services** and **EXEs** (more than 30). Each of the service/exe have one database class which have connection details and respective SQL queries.

Now, whenever some change come, our team need to maintain all the projects, which takes a lot of programmer's time and efforts. Also seems inappropriate.

I was wondering if there was a better architecture to manage such kind of structure. So that it can save programmer's time and repetitive effort.

> What I have think is that to maintain a common DLL, which will have
>   all the connection detail and SQL queries. Maintaining this structure
>   using inheritance will save a lot of repetitive effort.

Is there any better way to manage this? What are your opinions?

Comment: This is too vague/subjective to ask on SO. You could consider asking at software engineering stackexchange. But you answered it yourself, with some kind of common access. Even with a shared DLL though you would have to update and redeploy every project.

Comment: @NibblyPig I wanted to ask on SE but those sites are block in my company. Will delete this question if needed.

Comment: SO is not generally for asking opinions or architecture design. Much of it will depend on your architecture. For example in Azure you could define app settings that are shared across projects so you could update it in one place. But on IIS you would have to update app configs. Other hosting solutions such as azure's cached web.config you can't necessarily update the app config as it won't refresh. etc. etc.

The solution depends too much upon how your project fits together, what your needs are etc.

You could come up with an idea and present it as a question saying does this do what I want